# How to obtain the selected custom option value from options.phtm

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options, drop-downs

I'm trying to get the dropdown selected custom option value before the client adds the product to the checkout from

> /default/template/catalog/product/view/options.phtml

I have access to $_options object and I'm able to iterate over it and read all it's values

```
foreach ($_options as $key => $value) { 
                            $optionData = $value->getProduct()->getOptionById($key);                                
                            if($optionData['type'] == 'drop_down') {
                            foreach ($optionData->getValues() as $v) {                                  
                                Mage::log($v['option_type_id'],null,'customily.log');                                                                           
                            }                               
                         }                                          
                        }
```

[image]

But I need to obtain the selected one. How could I do it?